# Is it safe to set IFS for a for loop and then unset it inside the for loop?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix

Consider the following shell script that I intend to run on any [POSIX.1-2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) conformant shell.

```
log()
{
    echo debug: "$*"
}

A=foo:bar:baz

IFS=:
for i in $A
do
   log token ">>  >>" "$i"
done

unset IFS
# Do more stuff here
```

I want to loop over colon separated values. Within the loop I want to call a log function that should be able to echo all arguments passed to it intact with multiple whitespaces in each argument preserved. When I run this code, this is the output I get.

```
debug: token:>>  >>:foo
debug: token:>>  >>:bar
debug: token:>>  >>:baz
```

The good thing is that the two spaces in `">>  >>"` have been preserved because of the usage of `"$*"`, i.e. quoted special parameter asterisk as defined in [Section 2.5.2 Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) of POSIX.1-2004.

But the bad thing is that as a result of the same usage, the three arguments passed to `log` are now separated by colon (the `IFS`).

I solve this problem by `unset`ting the `IFS` within the `for` loop.

```
log()
{
    echo debug: "$*"
}

A=foo:bar:baz

IFS=:
for i in $A
do
   unset IFS
   log token ">>  >>" "$i"
done

unset IFS
# Do more stuff here
```

Now, the output is as I desire.

```
debug: token >>  >> foo
debug: token >>  >> bar
debug: token >>  >> baz
```

But I want to know if it is possible that in some POSIX shell, unsetting `IFS` within the `for` loop can have the side-effect of modifying the `IFS` for the `for` loop while it is in progress?

For example,  I worry that some POSIX shell might produce the following output for my second code example.

```
debug: token >>  >> foo
debug: token >>  >> bar:baz
```

Can someone tell me by citing the relevant sections from [POSIX.1-2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) if my second code example is safe, and if it is guaranteed to produce the same behavior in all POSIX compliant shells?

If my second code example is not safe, then I might have to settle for something like this that does not modify the `IFS`.

```
log()
{
    echo debug: "$*"
}

A=foo:bar:baz

echo "$A" | tr : "\n" | while read i
do
   log token ">>  >>" "$i"
done
```

Comment: Just a note re `unset IFS` this doesn't actually set it to default. Storing it in a temp variable as in the answer is a better solution. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97481/ifs-null-is-not-the-same-as-unset-ifs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is safe.

The `$A` variable will be expanded once before the for-loop starts executing:

```
for i in foo bar baz
```

Once that happens, any changes to IFS will have no effect.

Refs:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05

If you are  using IFS just to parse that string, you could do this:

```
oldIFS=$IFS IFS=:
set -- $A           # save the elements of the list as positional parameters
IFS=$oldIFS

for i; do
    log "$i"
done
```